Type does not satisfy pointer to interface in generic Go
Definitions
My interface
type FirestoreDocument interface {
    GetDocumentKey() string
    SetDocumentKey(key string)
}

A struct implementing it
type ImageProcessingJobDocument struct {
    documentKey  string
    Whatever     string    `firestore:"whatever"`
}

func (d *ImageProcessingJobDocument) GetDocumentKey() string {
    return d.documentKey
}

func (d *ImageProcessingJobDocument) SetDocumentKey(key string) {
    d.documentKey = key
}

Some generic code that tries to use the above.
Note - D is really a return type. I am not permitted to make Execute generic with Execute[D], presumably this is not supported by Go, but I can stick D on the struct below and eventually use it in the return tuple (D, error).
type FirestoreUpdate[T any, D *FirestoreDocument] struct {
    Collection string
    DocumentID string
    Data       T
}

func NewFirestoreUpdate[T any, D *FirestoreDocument]
(collection, documentID string, data T) *FirestoreUpdate[T, D] {
   ...
}

func (u *FirestoreUpdate[T, D]) Execute(ctx context.Context, client *firestore.Client) (D, error) {
    ...
}



Usage
Here's how I'm using it:
    firestoreUpdate := documents.NewFirestoreUpdate[*data.JobProcessingUpdate, 
        data.ImageProcessingJobDocument](documents.CollectionJobs, key, update)

Note - See that I am specifying two types in this generic method call, the first is a pointer and the second is not. The second one (the job document) is the one of interest.
Problem
When the second type is not a pointer (see above, Usage), I get:
data.ImageProcessingJobDocument does not satisfy *documents.FirestoreDocument (data.ImageProcessingJobDocument missing in *blah/internal/store/documents.FirestoreDocument)

And when I specify that the second type is a pointer, I get:
*data.ImageProcessingJobDocument does not satisfy *documents.FirestoreDocument (*data.ImageProcessingJobDocument missing in *blah/internal/store/documents.FirestoreDocument)

But when I do not specify the types but allow the compiler the infer them, then D ends up inferred as the interface FirestoreDocument.
I'm from a C# background and this sort of thing would work. In fact, I could just make the Execute method generic.
The pointers are what's really confusing, both in terms of constraints, generic placeholders (D vs. *D) but in this case with regards to the pointer receiver and how this might impact whether an interface is implemented by the type or not, and hence why neither the pointer nor direct value seem to satisfy the constraint/implement the interface.
The pointer modifier really confuses things with generics.

In Go, there is a principle to “accept interfaces, return structs.”
That means as long as you return an *ImageProcessingJobDocument, you should do so in the API:
func (u *FirestoreUpdate[T]) Execute(ctx context.Context, client *firestore.Client) (*ImageProcessingJobDocument, error) {
    return &ImageProcessingJobDocument{}, nil
}

Also, since you don't do anything with FirestoreDocument in the structure, it shouldn't probably be used in the definition:
type FirestoreUpdate[T any] struct {
    Collection string
    DocumentID string
    Data       T
}

Should you ever need to write a “generic method”, you could do:
func Execute[T any, D FirestoreDocument](ctx context.Context, u *FirestoreUpdate[T], client *firestore.Client) (D, error) {
    var d D
    return d, errors.New("not implemented")
}

See also “Why does Go not support methods with type parameters?“.
Generally, it's best to let clients define the interface they need instead of making them dependent on your package.

The link "Why does" was interesting thank you. See your point around "don't do anything with" in the struct but in that linked article it does say "Instead of methods with type parameters, use top-level functions with type parameters, or add the type parameters to the receiver type." that last part is what I have done.
I have solved the problem and it works and seems to be as recommended in that article - yet many downvotes.

You're welcome. Downvoting seems to be a method the get questions less relevant, but you could ask on meta.stackoverflow. Feel free to mark this answer as “accepted” if it was useful ;)

don't use pointers when you are receiving interfaces like here type FirestoreUpdate[T any, D *FirestoreDocument] struct { in Go interfaces are pointers, what is happening is that when you try to pass data.ImageProcessingJobDocument or *data.ImageProcessingJobDocument both of then will be checked as if there were an interface, to avoid this just remove the * from the receive of FirestoreUpdate and receive D FirestoreDocument directly.

Without knowing more of your code actual usage, it's hard to tell whether your design is any good. Anyway, to address your specific issue:
When you write the following:
func NewFirestoreUpdate[T any, D *FirestoreDocument](/* params */) *FirestoreUpdate[T, D] {
   // ...
}

You define the type constraint of D to be a pointer to an interface. That constraint is essentially meaningless. The pointer-to-interface type bears to connection to the interface's implementors such as ImageProcessingJobDocument.
The other way around, even if *ImageProcessingJobDocument (a concrete pointer type) satisfies the interface FirestoreDocument because it implements its methods, it has no relation to a pointer-to-FirestoreDocument.
What you want is to constrain D to a simple interface:
func NewFirestoreUpdate[T any, D FirestoreDocument](/* params */) *FirestoreUpdate[T, D] {
   // ...
}

and
type FirestoreUpdate[T any, D FirestoreDocument] struct {
    Collection string
    DocumentID string
    Data       T
}

Now D can be instantiated with a type that implements FirestoreDocument. Note that such an implementor is precisely *ImageProcessingJobDocument and not simply ImageProcessingJobDocument because you declared the methods with the pointer receiver.
Example playground: https://go.dev/play/p/WZPr2w1Sbdx

By defining a constraint without the * pointer it seems to allow me to choose a pointer to D or a direct D, when I come to use the code.
I had previously tried this but hit another issue which caused me to try the pointer constraint which led to the SO question, but I've solved the other issue.
The other issue was simply how to return a default of D, since the aim was to define a generic in the return tuple for Execute.
When there's an error, I could not return nil, err since nil was incorrect and my other attempts to try and return a "nothing" failed, in C# I'd use default(D).
Anyway, the syntax was this:
// remove the * to make the constraints all [T any, D FirestoreDocument]
// then return nothing like this;

func (u *FirestoreUpdate[T, D]) Execute(ctx context.Context, client *firestore.Client) (D, error) {
    
    var doc D
    err := doSomething()
    if (err) {
        return doc, fmt.Errorf("whoops: %w", err)
    }
    
    ...
}

